# My only account is not in the sudo group

Tags: users, sudo

I installed Ubuntu 11.10 with a username `fooname`. And then I did something like

```
sudo usermod -G vboxsf fooname
```

Then, guess what: no one is a sudoer. How can `fooname` be back as a sudoer?

In addition, what should I have executed to ADD `fooname` to the group `vboxsf`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will likely have to boot off a live CD or some other medium, mount the root partition of your main install, and edit the `/etc/group` file and add your user name to the `admin` group (that is, find the line starting with `admin` and add your user name to the fourth field).

Once that is done, you should be able to boot normally and have sudo privileges.  You'll probably want to reinstate your other group memberships.  On my system, I have the following:

- `james` (which is also my user name: you should have a group based on yours, and it should be your primary group membership)
- `adm`
- `dialout`
- `cdrom`
- `plugdev`
- `lpadmin`
- `admin`
- `sambashare`

You should be able to make these changes in the normal way.

To add a group membership without replacing all the others, the command you should have used is:

```
sudo usermod --append -G vboxsf fooname
```

Comment: A root shell in recovery mode could be enough. And better to use standard tools (like `gpasswd -a james admin`) than directly editing `group` file.

Comment: @enzotib Recovery mode worked. I had to exit the readonly mode to change the /etc/group file with gpasswd.